# Why should we put onload before send method

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am new to JavaScript and would like to ask about about AJAX, that is, why we put xhr.onload before xhr.send() since even if I put xhr.onload after xhr.send() all works perfectly. But majority of tutorials teach you to put onload before send() without proper explanation. So, should I use

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload=function(){
        if(this.status===200){
            let div=document.querySelector('div').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', './mir.txt');
    xhr.send();

})
```

Or

```
let btn = document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', './mir.txt');
    xhr.send();
 xhr.onload=function(){
        if(this.status===200){
            let div=document.querySelector('div').innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
        }
    }

})
```

and WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Use your first version.

Logically, in the situation where the browser has the response cached, then XHR could complete instantly, and then you try to add "onload" after the response has already loaded, then nothing will happen.

In reality, even when cached, I don't think this can happen because of how the browser engine works, but from the coding point of view, it looks like it *could* happen. So making the pattern have onload at the top removes all suspicion that such behaviour could occur. Possibly in older browsers, when people did tend to do XHR reuests manually, that kind of thing was an actual danger?

I do know, in the scenario where you *syncronously* load a request, it does matter, because the thread will be blocked (as well as the whole window) during the send until it completes.

Answer (score 0):

Onload is most frequently used within the  element to perform a script once a website has fully loaded (including script files, images, CSS files, etc.) So Its a good approach lets load all the dependency after that we make a API call or Ajax call to update our DOM.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to use **onload()** before **send()**, your first and second example shows that already.
2. **onload()** is an event of **XHR** Object (a property for the **load** event of XHR), so it'll execute automatically when a particular event satisfies during the XHR execution. The function called when an XMLHttpRequest transaction completes successfully. So, Using **onload()** property you just define/tell what needs to do when load event satisfied. You don't have to define if you don't need it.
3. **send()** is a method of XHR, not an event. so you need to call it if you want it. see reference link to see more about its behavior for synchronous and asynchronous call.

Ref:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequestEventTarget/onload